# How to find plim of a variable?

Tags: probability, distributions, convergence

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample of a population with uniform distribution in $(0, 1)$; and denote $Y_n = (X_1.X_2...X_n)^{1/n}$. How can I find $\operatorname{plim}$ of $Y_n$?

The definition of $\operatorname{plim}$ I'm using is the following:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}⁡P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)=0$$

What I have done so far is $Y=\lim_{n\to \infty} ⁡Y_n = 1$. Hence:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}⁡P(|Y_n-1|>\varepsilon)=0$. But I'm stuck here.

Comment: Hint: analyze $\log Y_n.$  It is elementary (and easy) to find its distribution.

Comment: I've concluded $Y_n$ converges to 0 in probability, is that correct?

Comment: I obtain a different answer.  One way to check a guess like this is to run a quick simulation.  Here is an example using `R`: `x <- runif(1e4); y <- exp(cumsum(log(x)) / seq_along(x)); plot(y, type="l")`

Comment: Weak law of large numbers gives the p-limit of $\ln Y_n$, from which you get the p-limit of $Y_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the hints I was provided, this is the solution:

$\ln⁡(Y_n )=\frac1n (\ln⁡(X_1 )+\ln⁡(X_2 )+\cdots+\ln⁡(X_n ) )$

$\ln⁡(Y_n )=\frac1n\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \ln⁡(X_i )$

$E[\ln⁡(X_i ) ]=\int_0^1 \ln⁡(x)\cdot 1\,  dx=-1$ ($1$ comes from pdf of $X_i$)

By Weak Law of Large Numbers, $$\ln⁡(Y_n ) \stackrel{p}\to E[\ln⁡(X_i ) ]=-1$$

Then by exp being continuous: $$e^{\ln⁡(Y_n )}=Y_n \stackrel{p}\to e^{-1}=1/e$$

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264) is a tutorial for formatting math here.

Comment: Thank you  StubbornAtom !!